# Running jQuery once body has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run a bit of JS once the body has loaded. My framework loads the header/footer from two different files that are static and the body is dynamic. Therefore reading online I could place the $(elem).load(function()) at the end of body and as the page loads it would run the function? I tried this briefly but it doesn't seem to work.

```
{%include file='/var/www/include/tpl/header.tpl'%}
<div id="contentMain">
        <h1>{%$heading%}</h1>
        {%if isset($Details)%}
                <h4>Details</h4>
                {%$Details%}
        {%/if%}
        {%$table%}
</div>
<div id="space">
&nbsp;
</div>
<script>
        $("#contentMain").load(function(){
                alert("It worked!");
                //run some stuff here
        });
</script>
{%include file='/var/www/include/tpl/footer.tpl'%}
```

Any help as to how to get this to work would be much appreciated!

Comment: the `<body/>` doesn't have a load event. Try using the window load event instead. However, in your case, the code won't get executed anyway until the elements are ready, therefore you don't need to wait at all.

Comment: document.ready ? loads after the document has loaded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you do not need to wait due to the location of your script. The script wont be parsed/executed till the elements above it are parsed. Therefore, it's safe to assume the contentMain div and it's descendants are ready to be manipulated.

```
{%include file='/var/www/include/tpl/header.tpl'%}
<div id="contentMain">
        <h1>{%$heading%}</h1>
        {%if isset($Details)%}
                <h4>Details</h4>
                {%$Details%}
        {%/if%}
        {%$table%}
</div>
<div id="space">
&nbsp;
</div>
<script>
    alert("It worked!");
    //run some stuff here
</script>
{%include file='/var/www/include/tpl/footer.tpl'%}
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has a handy-dandy little function that you can attach to the document to run functions once the body has loaded.  It is the [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Place code here to do stuff
});
```

Doing it this way, you can ensure that the body and all of its content has loaded before any of the stuff inside of the function runs.

Comment: I already have the ready function doing other bits and pieces in the <head>. That is loaded as a static template, which I dont really want to apply to every single page as the content is dynamic what the JS is changing my not necessarily be there. What I want to do is be able to load another function after an element has loaded. Can ready() be called more than once then?

Comment: @user2518122 Yes, it can be called an infinite number of times. If the dom is already ready, the callback will be invoked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery's document.ready.

On the header, Include jquery reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     alert("It worked!");
  });
</script>
</head>
```